# Override value of a key of a property file inside dependent JAR

Tags: java, spring

My application has a dependency which comes with default property file having key app_port=${app_port:8080} and property file is sourced in JAR now I want to override value of this key with 8081 and I created another property file and put app_port=${app_port:8081} but it is not overriding value when I am trying to access it using env.getProperty("app_port") or @Value("${app_port}")

I tried searching on web but what I found is for boot: https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#boot-features-external-config
If I pass the value using VM argument -Dapp_port=8081 it is working

Library code:

```
@PropertySources({
@PropertySource("classpath:config/config.properties")
})
public class MessagingConfig
```

My application code:

```
@PropertySources({
@PropertySource("classpath:config/app_config.properties")
})
public class AppConfig
```

Content of config/app_config.properties

```
app_port=${app_port:8081}
```

I need a way to override the value of app_port to 8081

Comment: use `Profiles` in spring

Comment: I am not using profile based property files.

Answer (score 0):

`app_port=${app_port:8081}` basically tells Spring to use the current value of `app_port` with a default value of 8081.

If you use `app_port=8081` inside `app_config.properties` instead, it should work.